# Is here somwere who would like to run a training program for about ROS for students?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At Wroclaw University of Technology we are planing with group o students to start adventure with ROS.
Location:
https://www.google.pl/maps/place/Wroc%C5%82aw/@51.1140941,17.0301444,13z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x470fe9c2d4b58abf:0xb70956aec205e0f5

Althought we didn't found anyone whe will be able to start learning students , staritng with the basics, and carrying on with course of how to create ROS based projects.

If here is someone who will be interested in sucha an oportunity, please contact.

My email: zbigniew.zelazny@pwr.edu.pl

Best Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198540/is-here-somwere-who-would-like-to-run-a-training-program-for-about-ros-for-students?/) by [Zac](https://answers.ros.org/users/20975/zac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your post seems more like an announcement or call-for attention, which suits better in the [general mailing list](http://wiki.ros.org/Support). I'd recommend to post there once, then move the discussion to somewhere more specific (the `ros-users` mailing list is only an entry point, may not be for elaborated discussions).

If you're thinking of educational projects that goes beyond an entry level working group, there's a special interest group for educational purposes.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ros-sig-education

Many tutorials, on/off ROS site, are available.
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2